# How to define xsd element name dynamic as complex type

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd, schema, xsd-validation

My application is consuming a json service and exposing it as soap web service to a client.

Provider has got one complex type element node, for which the name is dynamic. I want to return the same to my client

```
<xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Dynamic_name_coming_from_webservice" type="complex_type_it_is" />
```

This is how I need to define my element in XSD. How is this possible ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `xs:any` wildcard. However, a wildcard cannot constrain the content of the element to be a particular type. If there are constraints on the content, but no constraint on the name, your only way to define the constraints is by using XSD 1.1 assertions.